# Data missing em campo data/hora Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou enfrentando um problema com meu ambiente de produção e desenv do laravel. O ambiente desenv é linux (utilizando apache2 e php7.1, drives do sql server 2014 devidamente configurados) e o ambiente produção é um Windows utilizando o Xampp com php 7.2 (tambem com o drive do sql server 2014 devidamente cadastrado).

O problema é que no ambiente desenv todos os campos que utilizam a biblioteca Carbon:: esta gerando erro de "Data missing", já no ambiente de produção, o erro não ocorre.

Já verifiquei os timezone de ambos os arquivos php.ini e estão idênticos e mesmo assim, o erro persiste.

Comment: Tem como mostrar o log de erro? Mas, de qualquer forma eu vi esse erro parecido aqui (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968061/laravel-carbon-data-missing) qualquer dificuldade com o inglês use o Translator do Google.

Comment: Pessoal , consegui resolver. 
Era a versão do PHP. Atualizei o php 7.1 para o PHP 7.2 e funcionou.